# How do I join the vertical lines here in the table?

Tags: tables

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{times}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{helvet} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{courier}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{graphicx} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\urlstyle{rm} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\def\UrlFont{\rm}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{graphicx}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{natbib}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS AND DO NOT ADD ANY OPTIONS TO IT
\usepackage{caption} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS AND DO NOT ADD ANY OPTIONS TO IT
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pbox}
\frenchspacing  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\begin{document}
\begin{table*}[ht]
\centering
\begin{adjustbox}{width=0.9\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|cc|cc|cc|c}
\hline
\multirow{4}{*}{Network}  & \multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{Score\\ Type}} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{High SNR}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{Medium SNR}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\multirow{3}{*}{Low SNR}} &
\multirow{4}{*}{\makecell{Time\\per epoch\\(secs)}}\\ 
\\
& & MAE & PE (\%) & MAE & PE(\%) & MAE & PE(\%) & \\\hline \hline 

\multirow{2}{*}{SVR} 
& R & 8.89$\pm$2.07 & 100$\pm$0.00 &  9.23$\pm$1.85 & 100$\pm$0.00 &  9.70$\pm$1.38 & 100$\pm$0.00 & \multirow{2}{*}{---} \\ 
& E & 9.97$\pm$2.45 & 96.29$\pm$8.30 & 10.08$\pm$2.46 & 96.28$\pm$8.32 & 10.31$\pm$1.56 & 96.40$\pm$8.05 &     \\ \hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Lasso}                                                         
& R & 18.57$\pm$5.28 & 44.89$\pm$21.06 & 18.56$\pm$5.28 & 44.84$\pm$21.12 & 18.55$\pm$5.24 & 44.85$\pm$21.02 & \multirow{2}{*}{---} \\
& E & 18.60$\pm$3.58 & 43.19$\pm$8.66 &  18.60$\pm$3.57 & 42.95$\pm$8.50 &  18.61$\pm$3.56 & 43.01$\pm$8.61  &     \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}
\caption{....}
\label{table:tab2}
\end{table*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: Your table provides a textbook example of why using `\adjustbox` to shoe-horn a table into the available space tends to produce distinctly inferior results, typographically speaking.

Comment: Please make your code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the relevant pavkage. Do you use the `geometry` package? If so, pleasela slo include the corresponding settings as well.

Comment: I added the packages I use

Comment: Given the margin size it is impossible to fit this table into the textwidth while still keeping it readable. As Mico already pointed out, using `adjustbox` on a tabular is a bad idea since it not only results in inconsistent but can also result in illegibly small font sizes, as your example shows. If you can't change the margin sizes, either rotate the table to a landscape orientation or change the table design entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Here are three different examples showing how to...

1. make your code compilable,
2. get rid of the gaps in the vertical lines
3. fit your table into the available space without using `adjustbox`
4. improve the alignment of numbers inside of the table.

In the first two examples, I have removed `adjustbox` and instead used a landscape page for the wide table, while I entirely changed the table layout in the third example. In the second and third example, I have removed all vertical lines and replaced the horizontal ones by rules from the `booktabs` package. Additionally, I used the `siunitx` package in order to improve the alignment of the numbers:

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{times}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{helvet} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{courier}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage[hyphens]{url}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{graphicx} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\urlstyle{rm} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\def\UrlFont{\rm}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{graphicx}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\usepackage{natbib}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS AND DO NOT ADD ANY OPTIONS TO IT
\usepackage{caption} % DO NOT CHANGE THIS AND DO NOT ADD ANY OPTIONS TO IT
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{pbox}
\frenchspacing  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\setlength{\pdfpagewidth}{8.5in}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS
\setlength{\pdfpageheight}{11in}  % DO NOT CHANGE THIS

\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{c|c|cc|cc|cc|c}
\hline
\multirow{3}{*}{Network}  & \multirow{3}{*}{\makecell{Score\\ Type}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{3}{*}{High SNR}} & 
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Medium SNR}} &
\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\multirow{2}{*}{Low SNR}} &
\multirow{3}{*}{\makecell{Time\\per epoch\\(secs)}}\\ 
& & & & &  &  &  &     \\
& & MAE & PE (\%) & MAE & PE(\%) & MAE & PE(\%) & \\\hline \hline 

\multirow{2}{*}{SVR} 
& R & 8.89$\pm$2.07 & 100$\pm$0.00 &  9.23$\pm$1.85 & 100$\pm$0.00 &  9.70$\pm$1.38 & 100$\pm$0.00 & \multirow{2}{*}{---} \\ 
& E & 9.97$\pm$2.45 & 96.29$\pm$8.30 & 10.08$\pm$2.46 & 96.28$\pm$8.32 & 10.31$\pm$1.56 & 96.40$\pm$8.05 &     \\ \hline 
\multirow{2}{*}{Lasso}                                                         
& R & 18.57$\pm$5.28 & 44.89$\pm$21.06 & 18.56$\pm$5.28 & 44.84$\pm$21.12 & 18.55$\pm$5.24 & 44.85$\pm$21.02 & \multirow{2}{*}{---} \\
& E & 18.60$\pm$3.58 & 43.19$\pm$8.66 &  18.60$\pm$3.57 & 42.95$\pm$8.50 &  18.61$\pm$3.56 & 43.01$\pm$8.61  &     \\ \hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{....}
\label{table:tab2}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\centering
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{l l *{3}{S[table-format=2.2(3)]S[table-format=3.2(4)]} c}
\toprule
Network  
  & \makecell{Score\\ Type} 
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{High SNR} 
      & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Medium SNR} 
        & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low SNR} 
          & \makecell{Time\\per epoch\\(secs)}\\ 
\cmidrule(r){3-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-6} \cmidrule(l){7-8}
&   & {MAE}      & {PE (\%)}   & {MAE}      & {PE(\%)}    & {MAE}      & {PE(\%)}   & \\
\midrule
SVR 
& R & 8.89(207)  & 100(0)      &  9.23(185) & 100(0)      &  9.70(138) & 100(0)     & --- \\ 
& E & 9.97(245)  & 96.29(830)  & 10.08(246) & 96.28(832)  & 10.31(156) & 96.40(805) & --- \\
\midrule 
Lasso                                                        
& R & 18.57(528) & 44.89(2106) & 18.56(528) & 44.84(2112) & 18.55(524) & 44.85(2102) & --- \\
& E & 18.60(358) & 43.19(866)  & 18.60(357) & 42.95(850)  &  18.61(356) & 43.01(861) & --- \\ 
\bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\caption{....}
\label{table:tab2}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}


\begin{table}
\centering
\sisetup{separate-uncertainty=true}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5.5pt}
\begin{tabular}{l l S[table-format=2.2(3)]S[table-format=3.2(4)] c}
\toprule
Network 
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Score\\ Type}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{High SNR}
          & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Time per \\epoch (secs)}}\\ 
\cmidrule(r){3-4} 
&   & {MAE}      & {PE (\%)}    \\
\midrule
SVR 
& R & 8.89(207)  & 100(0)       & --- \\ 
& E & 9.97(245)  & 96.29(830)   & --- \\
\addlinespace
Lasso                                                        
& R & 18.57(528) & 44.89(2106)  & --- \\
& E & 18.60(358) & 43.19(866)   & --- \\ 
\midrule
Network 
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Score\\ Type}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Medium SNR}
          & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Time per \\epoch (secs)}}\\ 
\cmidrule(r){3-4} 
&   & {MAE}      & {PE (\%)}    \\
\midrule
SVR 
& R  &  9.23(185) & 100(0)      & --- \\ 
& E  & 10.08(246) & 96.28(832)  & --- \\
\addlinespace
Lass                            
& R  & 18.56(528) & 44.84(2112)  & --- \\
& E  & 18.60(357) & 42.95(850)   & --- \\ 
\midrule
Network 
  & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Score\\ Type}}
    & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low SNR}
          & \multirow{2}{*}{\makecell{Time per \\epoch (secs)}}\\ 
\cmidrule(r){3-4} 
&   & {MAE}      & {PE (\%)}    \\
\midrule
SVR 
& R  &  9.70(138) & 100(0)     & --- \\ 
& E  & 10.31(156) & 96.40(805) & --- \\
\addlinespace
Lass    
& R  & 18.55(524) & 44.85(2102) & --- \\
& E  &  18.61(356) & 43.01(861) & --- \\ 
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{....}
\label{table:tab2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks the second option worked and looks good to me.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't indicated how wide your document's margins are. Assuming they're about 1" wide each, it's actually possible to typeset the table in portrait mode *without* having to resort to the `\adjustbox` cudgel.

Since your document employs the `times` text font package, I would like to strongly encourage you to use a Times Roman math font package; one such package is `newtxmath`.

I would also like to encourage you to give a table a much more open "look", mainly by getting rid of all vertical rules and by using fewer, but well-spaced, horizontal rules by using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package.

[image]

---

Just to demonstrate the most unfortunate effects that using `\adjustbox` can have on tables, here's a screenshot of the table that's produced by your original code. Note, in particular, the wild disparity in font sizes of the body of the table on the one hand and of the caption on the other.

[image]

---

Finally, here's the code that produced the first screenshot.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,booktabs,multirow,makecell}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry} % set margins as needed
\usepackage{times,newtxmath} % use a Times Roman math font
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{$}c<{$}}
\newcommand\x[1][1]{\phantom{#1}} % for spacing adjustments
\newcommand\px{\mathord{\pm}} % "\pm" but without the spacing
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}## Heading ##
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} 
           l c *{6}{C} c }
\toprule
Network 
  & \makecell{Score\\Type} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{High SNR} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Medium SNR} 
  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Low SNR} 
  & \makecell{Time\\per epoch}\\ 
\cmidrule{3-4} \cmidrule{5-6} \cmidrule{7-8}
& & \text{MAE} & \text{PE (\%)} 
  & \text{MAE} & \text{PE (\%)} 
  & \text{MAE} & \text{PE (\%)}  
  & (secs) \\
\midrule

\multirow{2}{*}{SVR} 
& R & \x8.89\px2.07      & \x[1.]100\px\x0.00 & \x9.23\px1.85 
    & \x[1.]100\px\x0.00 & \x9.70\px1.38      & \x[1.]100\px\x0.00 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{--} \\ 
& E & \x9.97\px2.45      & 96.29\px\x8.30     & 10.08\px2.46 
    & 96.28\px\x8.32     & 10.31\px1.56       & 96.40\px\x8.05 & \\ 
\addlinespace
\multirow{2}{*}{Lasso}                                                         
& R & 18.57\px5.28       & 44.89\px21.06      & 18.56\px5.28 
    & 44.84\px21.12      & 18.55\px5.24       & 44.85\px21.02 
    & \multirow{2}{*}{--} \\
& E & 18.60\px3.58       & 43.19\px\x8.66     &  18.60\px3.57 
    & 42.95\px\x8.50     &  18.61\px3.56      & 43.01\px\x8.61 & \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*} 
\caption{\dots}
\label{table:tab2}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help